# Sql Server Contains search not Giving Result as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from table1 where contains(searchWord,"*comfort*")
```

I want result as

> Uncomfortable

with search Word in between but it is showing

> comfort xyz

only

Comment: I've edited your question to improve the layout and add the correct tags. Can you please make sure you do that yourself next time? There is plenty of guidance in the [help] on what is expected of users of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need contains function here. Searches for precise or fuzzy (less precise) matches to single words and phrases, words within a certain distance of one another, or weighted matches in SQL Server
You need simple predicate for the required result.

```
select * from table1 where searchWord like '%comfort%'
```